# How To Add Tags For Text Files In Windows 10

Tags: windows, tags

Is there a way to allow tagging of text files in Windows 10? I'm looking to filter text files in files explorer using tags. By default you can do it only with certain file types such as images, docs, etc.

Comment: I searched and came up empty, sorry. I suppose you could add tags in the file name itself. http://www.tagspaces.org/

Answer (score 5):

Try with FileMeta, I have added tags support on Windows 10 (x64) to .TXT files, and working OK ;)

https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta/releases

SOURCE: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-tags-for-unsupported-files-windows

TIP: To avoid error 0x80004005 just click "Restart Explorer" on File Assotiation Manager.

ADVICE: if you move between NTFS and FAT, these properties will be lost. If you stay on in the same file system, then the tags stay, else you will lose them.

Answer (score 1):

Try Tagspaces or Turtl or some alternative. Win10 stupid about allowing tags for only certain kinds of files [ https://zapier.com/blog/how-to-use-tags-and-labels/]. I'm only figuring it out myself but I have thousands of tags & potential tags so the folders-as-tag option not all that useful, or not enough alone. [Microsoft! We make the complicated easy and the easy almost impossible!]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use shortcuts as an alternative to tags. I.e. somewhere in your folder structure, create folders where each folder represents a tag. Drag shortcuts for files to the appropriate “tag” folder. If you desire, add these tag folders to your shortcuts area (quick access area) in file explorer for quicker access. These folders now act as your tags to see “tagged” files under them.

If you really want to be clever, change the icons for these folders to something that represents a “tag” to you, for a better visual effect in your file explorer.

Comment: If you changed your file structure then you'd need some way to rewrite all your shortcut links.